# Division in python2.7 does not produce decimal values

Tags: python, floating-point, division

Here is my project on a small scale. The purpose is to approximate pi. I know it isn't neat, but the algorithm is correct.

```
adds = 0
subtracts = 0
for x in range(0, 10):
    adds += 1/(1 + 4*x)
    subtracts += 1/(3 + 4*x)
    print(adds) #DEBUGGING
    print(subtracts) #DEBUGGING

pi = float(4*(adds + subtracts)
print(pi)
```

Seems like it should work, right? On python 3, the same exact code gives me an accurate answer. However, in 2.7.10, this happens in the shell:

```
===================== RESTART: C:/Python27/Scripts/pi.py 
=====================
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
4.0
>>>
```

**Can someone explain to me why this happens and how I can correct this?** I have tried conventional methods like converting to strings, formatting, rounding, etc. but none of them work. It is like my variables are being saved as 1's and 0's despite their values constantly changing. Once again, the same code works fine on Python 3.

Comment: Python 2 uses integer division

Comment: Enter your numbers as floats and it will work.

Comment: It's been solved and explained already.

Answer (score 2):

On python2, division between integers results in integer division with the final answer truncated to a whole number.

```
>>> 1 / 2
0
```

On python3, this is not the case, because division automatically results in a `float` result unless you use the `//` integer division operator explicitly.

You'll want to have at least one of the operands of `float` type:

```
>>> 1. / 2
0.5
```

---

```
for x in range(0, 10):
    adds += 1. / (1 + 4 * x)
    subtracts += 1. / (3 + 4 * x)
```

Note the `1.` is `1.0`.

Comment: That works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

On Python 2.7, `x / y` is integer division, but you can use Python 3's real division using `__future__ division` :

```
from __future__ import division
adds = 0
subtracts = 0
for x in range(0, 10):
    adds += 1/(1 + 4*x)
    subtracts += 1/(3 + 4*x)
    print(adds) #DEBUGGING
    print(subtracts) #DEBUGGING

pi = float(4*(adds + subtracts))
print(pi)
```

Out :

```
1.0
0.333333333333
1.2
0.47619047619
1.31111111111
0.5670995671
1.38803418803
0.633766233766
1.44685771745
0.686397812714
1.49447676507
0.729876073583
1.53447676507
0.76691311062
1.56895952369
0.799171175136
1.59926255399
0.827742603708
1.62628958102
0.853383629349
9.91869284146
```

Comment: Be careful changing the mechanics of the syntax, you might not expect this behaviour in every place.

Comment: People are more familiar with `/` as being real division, that's one of the reasons it was changed in later versions, and changing it wouldn't be bad as long as you know how to use it.